# How to combine values of one column based on the value of the other

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame named target.

| time_stamp | user_id | visited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-04-22 03:53:30 | 1 | 1 |
| 2013-11-15 03:45:04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2013-11-29 03:45:04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2013-12-09 03:45:04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2013-12-25 03:45:04 | 3 | 1 |

I would like to create a new data frame df, which has two columns user_id which are unique user_id numbers. and times which is a list of timestamps for when that user_id logged in.

I created another table to show the user id as a column and the corresponding timestamps in a list on another column but I can't publish the question because some sort of using code error keeps popping up.

iterating through the rows didn't work and I was also unsuccessful going through a for loop.

thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False)['time_stamp'].agg(list)`

Comment: This question was closed because the powers that be said it was too similar to "How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby". I just wanted to point out that it is only similar if you know that you need to use group by. the person that is asking might not know. When i wrote the question, I looked at the related questions and this question never came up.

Comment: @-mozway, thank you, that did it. I tried playing around with groupby but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: that's fine that you didn't know. The benefit of having closed questions is also to help future readers find the answer. Even if, like you, they didn't know about `groupby` ;)